# Replace carriage returns and line feeds in out.println?

Tags: java, string, escaping, carriage-return

I am a novice coder and I am using the following code to outprint a set of Image keywords and input a "|" between them.

```
<% Set allKeywords = new HashSet();
for (AlbumObject ao : currentObjects) {
XmpManager mgr = ao.getXmpManager();
if (mgr != null) {
allKeywords.addAll(mgr.getKeywordSet());    
  }
}
//get the Iterator
Iterator itr = allKeywords.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
  String str = itr.next();
out.println(str +"|");   
} %>
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
red|blue|green|yellow
```

but it prints out:

```
red|
blue|
green|
yellow
```

which breaks my code. I've tried this:

```
str.replaceAll("\n", "");  
str.replaceAll("\r", "");
```

and

```
str.replaceAll("(?:\\n|\\r)", "");
```

No luck. I'd really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`out.print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) instead.  That way you don't have to contend with the unwanted newlines.

Comment: Well, a Duh moment for me. thanks. Each one a learning experience and humbling!

Comment: @Mike No worries.  I'm sure I was several weeks into learning Java before I found out about plain `print`.